# Add CRS to TIFF downloaded with owslib

Tags: python, wms, getmap, owslib

I'm using owslib to download an aerial photograph. In the WMS GetMap request I specify a srs, so I assume (maybe wrongly?) that the response I get contains a crs.

When writing the result to a GeoTiff the file doesn't contain spatial information. Is there a way to do this or do I have to use GDAL to project the result, and if so, how?

This is the code I'm using so far:

```
from owslib.wms import WebMapService
import gdal
from osgeo import osr

wms_url = 'https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/luchtfoto/rgb/wms?'
wms = WebMapService(wms_url,version = '1.3.0')


img = wms.getmap(layers=['Actueel_ortho25'],
                 srs='EPSG:28992',
                 bbox=(97712,440638,98220,441091),
                 size=(1000,1000),
                 format='image/GeoTIFF',
                 transparent=False)

out = open('path\\to\\test.tiff','wb')
out.write(img.read())
out.close()

print('done')
```

Answer (score 2):

As it currently stands, you will need to track the CRS information on the side or write it to the image yourself.

The [documentation](https://geopython.github.io/OWSLib/#wms) doesn't seem to mention it, but WMS layer objects have a `.crs_list` attribute, whose last member <s>is</s> seems to be the default EPSG system for that layer.

```
from owslib.wms import WebMapService
url = 'http://maps.geogratis.gc.ca/wms/hydro_network_en?service=wms'
wms = WebMapService(url, version='1.3.0')
wms['hydro_network'].crs_list

>>> [(-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0, 'EPSG:4269')]
```

Layers also have a `.crsOptions` attribute, which lists all the available CRSes for that layer.

```
wms['hydro_network'].crsOptions

>>> ['EPSG:26710',
     'EPSG:26909',
     'EPSG:32184',
     'EPSG:32196',
     'EPSG:3574',
     'EPSG:26915',
     etc.....
```

Answer (score 1):

So let's separate your questions.

If a WMS specifies `image/GeoTIFF` then the expectation would be that if you request such an image through a GetMap request like below, then the image returned should have projection information embedded:

`https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/luchtfoto/rgb/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&version=1.3.0&crs=EPSG:28992&layers=Actueel_ortho25&width=1000&height=1000&format=image/GeoTIFF&styles&transparent=FALSE&bbox=97712,440638,98220,441091&EXCEPTIONS=XML&BGCOLOR=0xFEFFFF&`

But I see that, as you say, it doesn't:

```
hodor@Mini ~/REST/downloads $ gdalinfo -proj4 wms.tiff
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: wms.tiff
Size is 1000, 1000
Coordinate System is `'
PROJ.4 string is:
''
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 1000.0)
Upper Right ( 1000.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 1000.0, 1000.0)
Center      (  500.0,  500.0)
Band 1 Block=1000x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=1000x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=1000x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

So I would regard that as an error of the server software.

> In the GetMap request I specify a srs, so I assume (maybe wrongly?) that the response I get contains a crs.

The assumption is wrong.

Generally, images (png, jpeg, gif, tiff...) requested by a client through a GetMap request are **not** georeferenced.  The client requests an image for a location specified by a bounding box (in the coordinates of the projection the client is working with) and the server sends back the image; it doesn't need to be georeferenced because the client knows where to put it.  So if you want a georeferenced image you will need to do the extra work based on the request parameters.

> Is there a way to do this?

Not in owslib, because you can't make a request do do this through a WMS, other than a standard GetMap request where the image format is GeoTIFF, and the server sends a GeoTIFF.

> or do I have to use GDAL to project the result, and if so, how?

You should probably ask another more focussed question